# Retrieving UC Browser history

Tags: android, browser-history, uc-browser

I'm trying to retrieve the history of a few browsers (on API <= 22), and while the history of default browsers & Chrome is available through the following code, UC Browser's data in unavailable:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS };
String searchCondition = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0 OR visits > 0";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, columns, searchCondition, null, null);
```

Any idea how can I retrieve this data? The project's decompiled code is huge and without readable names I don't manage to find anything useful in it.

Thanks.

Comment: "Any idea how can I retrieve this data?" -- contact the developers of the app and ask them if they have a supported, secure API for this data.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping that someone here is already aware of such API (or of its absence).